# Making vim git aware

Tags: git, vim

1. I use Vim & Git together.
2. I tend to merge/switch Git branches alot.
3. I tend to have lots of vim buffers open.
4. Is there a way to tell vim: when I execute this git command (which switches branches), *reload* all buffers? Since I have hooks into all my vim-git interaction, letting vim know when to do the reload is not a problem. The question is: how to force vim to reload all buffers?

Comment: If I may ask, how do you have vim and git tied together so closely?

Comment: The [vim-fugitive](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim---a-complement-to-command-line-git/) plugin provides something like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try setting the `autoread` option on.

```
:set autoread
```

From the vim help:

> When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and
>   it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.